# Opening Unity doesn’t work out

Tags: gnome, unity, software-installation, 22.10, snap-store

I am new to Linux and wanted to get started in Unity. I have watched many tutorials and I have searched the docs. The problem is, that when I open Unity I always get an other screen than the one in the docs or tuts shown. There are only 2 Options: sign in or register. No matter which you choose, you are getting to the browser. And then I get a error stating that there are no apps available to open Unity. Then it wants me to open the software store but I get another error.

Comment: You've tagged two different desktops & its unclear what you're actually using & asking about. Are you using Ubuntu 22.10 using GNOME? or Ubuntu Unity 22.10 using the Unity Desktop? or did you install GNOME & then added the `ubuntu-unity-desktop` or something? or something else when you mention Unity?  (Unity Game engine? etc)  Why tag two different desktops? which are you using?

Comment: Well, when I try to log in on the browser, I mentioned that I get an error stating that there is no app available to open Unity. When clock on Open Software(the place where you can install things) I get an error with Gnome. And yes I meant the Game Engine

Comment: This is a Q&A site & not a forum, thus when providing additional details or clarifications please edit your question & add details there. Your question currently refers to the Unity Desktop and GNOME Desktop (*it's what you tagged the question as being about; you didn't tag the Unity Game engine but Unity Desktop!*) so correct your question then as it's still unclear. Any answers will be to your question; where you select Unity at login (ie. before logging into GNOME), as only one of GNOME or the Unity Desktop can be running at the same time